# Should we use "before" or "earlier" at the end of a past perfect sentence?

Tags: adverbs

Should we use "before" or "earlier" at the end of a past perfect sentence?

Example 1:

> When I was 20, I decided to try what I had never tried **before/earlier**.

Example ２:

> At 20, I did what I had never done **before/earlier**: going fishing and going surfing.

Answer (score 1):

*Before* is used when referring to a previous occasion when the same thing happened to you. If this is/was your first time, you say

> I have/had not/never done it before.

*Earlier* is used when referring to something in the fairly recent past.

> She posted the parcel which she had wrapped earlier.
>
> I went to see Professor Brown, having telephoned earlier to check that he was free.

Comment: Nah. *I just did [what I had done before*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22what+I+had+done+before%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I didn't mean to imply that you _couldn't_ say 'what I had done before', just that we say 'I haven't done it before' rather than 'I haven't done it earlier'.

Comment: I just don't think "first time you have ever done something" is a useful characteristic to identify before deciding whether to use ***earlier*** or ***before*** in any given context. Not to mention which *...having telephoned **first** to check that he was free* is perfectly idiomatic in your second example, despite having no implications as regards whether you'd ***ever*** phoned the professor previously / before / earlier. Note that I don't seriously expect my downvote to stand here - offhand I don't know how to explain things to OP, but I'm willing to bet you can improve this answer!

Comment: ...I can't think of any reason to quibble with ***Earlier** is used when referring to something in the fairly recent past*, and *maybe* that's all that's needed by way of "explanation" here. If you'd *never* done something ***before***, it wouldn't make much sense to deny having done it "recently / earlier".

Comment: "I did what I had done before" is, in fact, exactly as Kate says: "referring to a previous occasion when the same thing happened."  Re-read her answer and notice she gave "first time you have ever done something" as an indication that one should use "never done it before", not as a means of "deciding whether to use earlier or before in any given context".

Comment: *Earlier* can be used in the distant past, but it suggest two events that may be unconnected or separated in time, while *before* is more likely to imply a direct relationship between the two events. *Earlier* is often used when talking about specific times; it often means earlier in the day/year/etc, while *before* is much vaguer and implies a contrast with *after*. "Mary was executed at noon. Earlier she had written a letter to her sister..."